# JS onclick function passing external file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a menu which is plain HTML In there I have some images. When you click on those an action should be preformed (for example opening or closing the menu). This plain HTML menu is included by PHP.

To preform an action, I thought adding the JS onclick="" tag to my HTML would be a good idea. Now I have created some .js files that are in a subdirectory called js.

Now is my question how to pass the .js files located in the subdir to the onclick="" tag.

(TLDR)

/index.php <- there is the navigation bar inside

/js/file.js <- want to access this file via onclick="" in index.php

How can I do that

Comment: i can't really get what you want to do? seams like you just need some simple JS tutorial? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: @TheWuif I want to do the following: onclick="./js/file.js" but this throws an error and onclick="js/file.js" doesn't work

Comment: you can't call a file in an onclick, that is not how onclick works. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: To literally do what you asked you'd have to write `onclick="var s=document.createElement('script');s.src='./js/file.js';document.body.appendChild(s)"` but that's most likely the wrong approach overall. You should have your script loaded and ideally attach an event listener from the script, or otherwise set some global function there and call it in onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to access some JavaScript in an external file, just include that file in your index.php like this.

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Then you can call your JavaScript functions in the "onclick" method as if it was written on the same page.

```
onclick="yourMethod()" //your method name here
```

Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to put this `<script src="/js/file.js"></script>` before your `</body>` tag (or footer if you want) then call the functions inside with `onclick` or `onload` event. Provide more details if you need more clarification.